How to display "To:" address instead of "From:" in Thunderbird
I am using Thunderbird to archive old messages from my Gmail account. Using IMAP, I'm copying selected messages to my Local Folders, then deleting the Gmail copies via Thunderbird.
My Local Folders structure looks like this:
{Gmail account}
├───Inbox
├───Drafts
└───Sent Mail

Local Folders
├───Gmail_2006-2010
│   └───Sent
├───Gmail_2011-2015
│   └───Sent
└───Gmail_2016-2020
    └───Sent

It has worked well; I'm happy with my local archive. However, when viewing any of the local "Sent" folders, every email shows my name instead of the recipient's. I would have thought it would be easy to change the display from "From" to "To", but I can't figure it out...
If I look at the "Sent Items" folder under the Gmail account (within Thunderbird, not the Gmail web interface), the message are displayed with the desired "To:" values.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?
Thunderbird 128.1.0esr on Windows 11.

New information after user LPChip's help:
I had been in Cards View instead of Table View, and so couldn't see the column headers. This selection is a global setting for all folders. But after uncovering the headers there is another problem:
In Table View, in both the Gmail "Sent Items" and in my Local Folder's "Sent", the recipient's names are displayed correctly (in both cases, with a little arrow to indicate "To" instead of "From").
But when I switch back to Cards Mode, the Gmail folder shows the recipient's name but the Local folder shows the sender's name?!
Where can I determine which fields are shown in Card View?

Thunderbird will save each column layout per folder.
So you can go to each sent folder, then add the column Recipient by right-clicking a column header and selecting the column you wish to add.
You can drag it to the location of where the Correspondents column is, and then uncheck the Correspondents column.
Once you are satisfied with one sent folder, you can right-click the column headers again, and choose apply colums to -> and select each sent folder.

Thanks! This is helpful, but uncovers a new wrinkle to the question. Could you look at my updated question?

Please don't edit a question to change it, but ask a new question instead. This will push your question to the top and makes it so that old answers are not obsolete and get downvoted for the wrong reasons.
